# changing size of Widget from QStyle

Tags: qt, qt4.7

I am writting a `QStyle` Here I am changing the QProgressBar to a Slim single line, no text. So Height will also be reduced to 5px. However Widget Width will be determined by layout. what should I do in My Style's `drawControl` to change widget height ?

Comment: I think it would be much easier for you to simply call setMaximumWidth(5pixels) and setMinimumWidth(5pixels) which will constrain the width to 5 pixels no matter what the layout is.

Answer (score 1):

I've never actually written a `QStyle` but I would consider it odd if you were supposed to resize anything inside `drawControl`. I could be wrong on this by a quick review of the documentation would seem to suggest that you would override [subElementRect](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qstyle.html#subElementRect) and return a rect based on current width and your preferred height. I assume this would be called by layout activities and would be sorted out by the time `drawControl` gets called.

Comment: I've tried in all 3 ProgressBar related Sub Elements Case `SE_ProgressBarGroove`, `SE_ProgressBarContents`, `SE_ProgressBarLabel` I am returning a rect with height 5px and of same width. Which is not working. No change Its still the Same.

Comment: Sorry that didn't work. Hopefully more suggestions will appear.

Comment: So setting a maximum height of 5 on the progress bar widget doesn't work?

Comment: I've tried overridding `polish(QWidget* widget)` and there `widget->setGeometry(rect)` which didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the height for the widget to be fixed?  Or just the drawn height to never go past 5 pixels?  For the first, set the height *and resize policy* on the polish function.  For the second, override the drawing in the QStyle to only use 5 pixels.  The functions that do the drawing generally take rects; you can call the base class's draw with a modified rect if you properly override the appropriate functions.  Unfortunately, it's been years since I've done any QStyle work, so I'm not sure exactly what those functions are.